# SQL Server : unexpected performance issue between in-line and stored procedure execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, sqlperformance

I have run into an enigma of sorts while researching a performance issue with a specific stored procedure. I did not create that stored procedure, and the logic is fairly ugly with nested selects in join statements, etc...

However, when I copy the logic of the stored procedure directly into a new query window, add the parameters at the top and execute it, this runs in under 400 milliseconds. Yet, when I call the stored procedure and execute it with the exact same parameter values, it takes 23 seconds to run!

This makes absolutely no sense at all to me!

Are there some server-level settings that I should check which could potentially be impacting this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to check out parameter sniffing.

Comment: Please add the query, table *and index* definitions, and share query plans for both versions via https:/brentozar.com/pastetheplan. It is most likely [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) combined with poor plan options, stale and/or skewed statistics

Comment: Very likely parameter sniffing. You could try removing the execution plan(s) for the procedure from cache (look at `dbcc freeproccache <planhandle>`) and rerunning the proc, you could try recreating the procedure with `option recompile`, if the problem goes away then it is - although that's not a long term fix.

Comment: TL;DR, [parameters<>local variables or literals](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Cached execution plans are based on the hash of the entire statement (including whitespace) and the current @@OPTIONS. It's not surprising that executing the statements in a query window outside of the stored procedure may yield a different plan. Another interesting read for you: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Answer (score 0):

Recompile your stored procedure.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) says

> When a procedure is compiled for the first time or recompiled, the procedure's query plan is optimized for the current state of the database and its objects. If a database undergoes significant changes to its data or structure, recompiling a procedure updates and optimizes the procedure's query plan for those changes. This can improve the procedure's processing performance.

and

> Another reason to force a procedure to recompile is to counteract the "parameter sniffing" behavior of procedure compilation. When SQL Server executes procedures, any parameter values that are used by the procedure when it compiles are included as part of generating the query plan. If these values represent the typical ones with which the procedure is subsequently called, then the procedure benefits from the query plan every time that it compiles and executes. If parameter values on the procedure are frequently atypical, forcing a recompile of the procedure and a new plan based on different parameter values can improve performance.

If you run the SP's queries yourself (in SSMS maybe) they get compiled and run.

How to recompile your SP? (See the doc page linked above.)

- You can rerun its definition to recompile it once. That may be enough if the procedure was first defined long ago in the life of your database and your tables have grown a lot.
- You can put `CREATE PROCEDURE ... WITH RECOMPILE AS` into its definition so it will recompile every time you run it.
- You can `EXEC procedure WITH RECOMPILE;` when you run it.
- You can restart your SQL Server. (This can be a nuisance; booting the server magically makes bad things stop happening and nobody's quite sure why.)

Recompiling takes some time. But it takes far less time than a complex query with a bad execution plan would.

Comment: Recompiling once is highly unlikely to fix the problem. Statistics are normally updated automatically when tables grow. And you haven't mentioned `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` (not that I would recommend the latter)

Answer (score 0):

So...  I ended up turning the nested selects on the joins to table variables, and now the sproc is executing in 60-milliseconds, while the in-line sql is taking 250=ms.

However, I still do not understand why the sproc was performing so much slower than the in-line sql version with the original nested sql logic?

I mean, both were using the exact same sql logic, so why was the sproc taking 23-seconds while the in-line was 400-ms?

Comment: For anyone dealing with issues like this, the answer is always in the execution plan--though it may take some digging to understand.

Comment: A Table Variable is almost always better than a nested join, so this should become a standard in your development.  However, the issue with the drastic difference between your Sproc and In-LIne SQL execution was definitely something in the compiled execution plan.  I have run into this exact same issue a couple of times in the past, and using Table variables cleared it up both times.  Who really knows why SQL does this?

Comment: I'm leery of that assessment. Table variables are fundamentally a different tool because they force the subquery to be fully materialized. If the outer query ends with `where id = @id`, the execution plan will almost certainly use that condition to limit the extent of the nested join, whereas using a table variable could very well needlessly materialize the entirety of one or more tables.

Comment: Okay, so yes I misspoke there...  if the data in the nested join is a significant size reduction over the parent table, then it is always better to use a table variable.